# Migrate from Aptly to jfrog Artifactory

Tags: migration, debian, artifactory, jfrog-cli

We are currently using Aptly for Debian package management. we want to migrate to Jfrog artifactory.

Tried to setup remote repository in Artifactory. But artifactory supports replication only from another artifactory server.

Exploring options like copying deb files and put it in artifactory file system and recalculate index. Is it possible? any other suggestion?

Note: we have 10 TB(160k) deb packages. Adding one by one would be time consuming.

Comment: I think you are confusing Artifactory's remote repository and replication.
You can set up a remote repo pointing to a non-Artifactory repo. Replication means the actual copying of artifacts from one server to another. Using a remote repo you basically "proxy" that remote repository in your local Artifactory, and only items that are "requested" from the remote repo are cached locally.
you can read more here - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Management#RepositoryManagement-RemoteRepositories

Comment: I understand that @Ortsigat Since mirroring is a concept in debian repositories I thought Artifactory might have that feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct way to do this however I recommend you to do the following:

1. Create a remote repository in Artifactory and point it to Aptly
2. Get the list of packages from Aptly
3. Send a head request to each package so that the package will land in the remote repository cache
4. Use a plugin to move the packages from remote repository cache to a local repository. This [plugin](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/storage/createCopy) might be helpful to you

of course, you need to script this process as the data is high.

Comment: Thanks @LakshmiPrasad I will check this plugin